# which server did I use,when I configure django admin tool after typing "python manage.py runserver"?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-2.6

I am configuring django for using django admin tool, following steps in webpage http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-django/?S_TACT=105AGX52&S_CMP=cn-a-l

which server did I use,when I type "python manage.py runserver"? apache? or a simple http server in python?
And I have apache 2.2 listening port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Django's development server, which as you say is a simple http server written in Python, and runs in the Python process you start with the "python manage.py runserver" command.  Note that this server is not meant for production use.  For example, it can handle only one request at a time.

Comment: I am developing python web app in vmware virtual machine with IP 10.7.6.8, I can browser website in APACHE server on Host machine, but I cant browser django manage webpage using http://10.7.6.8:8000, why? Is it too simple? apache is listening on port 80. But I can open it with 127.0.0.1:8000 in virtual machine.

Comment: I have solved this. It need type shell command as "python manage.py runserver 10.7.6.8:8000".